# Weka RF doesn't give any confusion matrix or expected results

Tags: random-forest, weka

I am using WEKA to classify a small dataset with only 27 instances into a binary classification. I have tried with bigger datasets and weka show the confusion matrix and the other metrics, but with my main and small 27 instances dataset only shows this:

```
    Scheme:       weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 100 -num-slots 1 -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1
Relation:     t_PROMIS_mtbi-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R1
Instances:    27
Attributes:   7
              Var2
              Var3
              Var4
              Var5
              Var6
              Var7
              ERS
Test mode:    10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

RandomForest

Bagging with 100 iterations and base learner

weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1 -do-not-check-capabilities

Time taken to build model: 0.01 seconds

=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.0348
Mean absolute error                      0.4544
Root mean squared error                  0.529 
Relative absolute error                 91.7269 %
Root relative squared error            102.952  %
Total Number of Instances               27
```

i don't undersantd why this is happening. Is it a size thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already solved it, The problem was that i was using numbers 1/0 on my class viariable, I changed it for a "Yes"/"No" variable and works.